# Will I have the opportunity to catch them again?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

Once I have encountered and defeated Cobalion, Virizion and Terrakion, will I have the opportunity to capture them at a later time?

Comment: I haven't played a pokemon game in quite some time, but typically you only had one chance to fight and catch legendary pokemon

Comment: That was the case previously, but I think some more recent games have been having them come back after you leave the area (edit: or, apparently, defeat the champion again) or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Ever since Ruby & Sapphire, [if you knock out or flee from a legendary Pokémon or (starting in HGSS) a fixed-location Pokémon like R36's Sudowoodo, the Pokémon will reappear](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rematch#Legendary_and_special_encounter_Pok.C3.A9mon) after the next time you defeat the Elite Four & Champion; if you defeat them again, they'll reappear again after you enter the Hall of Fame once more, and so on until you finally capture them.  In the case of the Swords of Justice (Cobalion, Terrakion, and Virizion) in B2W2, [according](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova_Route_13#Pok.C3.A9mon_Black_2_and_White_2) [to](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova_Route_22#Pok.C3.A9mon) [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova_Route_11#Pok.C3.A9mon_Black_2_and_White_2), they all reappear in the same location at a higher level: while they are all level 45 the first time you encounter them, if you don't catch them the first time, they go up to level 65.

Comment: Oh, even Snorlaxes come back? Good to know.

Comment: @ZAD-Man: Actually, on looking into it further, it appears non-legendary Pokémon only started respawning in HGSS.  So it applies to the HGSS and XY Snorlaxes, but not the RBY or FRLG ones.

Comment: Ahh, OK, that explains why I wasn't aware, as I haven't finished any of those games where it applies yet.

Answer (score 0):

Very sure you run into them twice, if you do not capture them the first time they will appear later at a higher level in a different location. I know they have the answer for sure on Serebii.net. On that site just find Black&White 2 on the left and look up event pokemon on the right I believe.